# Render page on react after loading json

Tags: reactjs, json, async-await

I have load() function:

```
async function load() {
    let url = `www.com/file.json`
    let data = await (await fetch(url)).json()
    return data
}
```

I need to render my page after loading my json file from server:

```
export const Page = async () => {
    const data_ = await load()
    return (
          <div className="page">
                content
          </div>
    )
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `useEffect` hook to make the call when the component mounts, it will be called once and fetch the data you need, then it will set it in the `data` state to be used in the return inside the divs.

As you did not provide the structure of the response I cannot give a more detailed explanation on how to render the data itself. Also `id_` has no use in your example but I kept it there to closely resemble your example.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

export const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async (id_) => {
        let url = `www.com/file.json`
        let data = await (await fetch(url)).json()
        const manipulatedData = ...
        // do manipulation
        setData(manipulatedData)
    }
    load()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="page">
      {data ? data : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: Looks cool! But how can i use it like:
`const [renderFlag, setRenderFlag] = useState(false)`
`return (<div>{renderFlag && <div>done!</div>}</div>)`
?

Comment: Can you please define what are you trying to achieve? Also, I added my answer a bit as I was not entirely accurate about causing an infinite loop. It seems it will not happen for this specific code.

Comment: I want to make some manipulations with data from json before render. So i (probably) want to make flag, and render page after setFlag(true). Smth like that

Comment: Please have a look again, I changed the code a bit to reflect your desire. I don't think you need another state, just manipulate the data and then set it to the state. We can use data itself to check if there is something inside, if not it will not render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect` and `useState`

Here's how you could achieve this:

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      let url = `www.com/file.json`;
      let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
      setData(data);
    }

    load();
  }, []);

  return <div className="page">{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}
```

Replace `JSON.stringify` with `data.something` to show a particular field in the data

A couple of tips:

- React components cannot be async functions
- `useState` carries variables you need to render the page
- `useEffect` is a function that lets your component handle calling async code or any other kind of `side effect`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook `useEffect()` & `useState()` to load your data :

```
function load() {
    let url = `www.com/file.json`
    let data = await (await fetch(url)).json()
    return data
}

export const Page = async () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    load().then((_data) => {
       setData(_data)
    })

  }, [])

  if (!data) {
    return <div>loading data...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div className="page">
      data is ready to use !
    </div>
  )
}
```